# How to persist real time data efficiently on a socket.io and express web application without making many calls to Postgres database?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, websocket, socket.io

I'm a newbie currently working on a portfolio project which is trying to implement a real-time comment section component using web sockets. I am wondering how to persist the data most efficiently, i.e., how do I persist the new comments that are posted in real-time without making expensive calls to the database every single time a new comment is made?

From my understanding, you could obviously just save each new entry into the database every single time a comment is posted, but I was thinking that this would be very expensive at high volumes because you would be making a call to the database every single time. I was wondering if what you could do is save the new comments to a global cache first, and then periodically update the database from the cache once X amount of new information has been cached or X amount of time has passed? Was just an idea. Would love to know what the best practice is and how to go about it!

Comment: How many comments per second do you expect? We handle thousands of events per second on a single database instance without any issues

Comment: Realistically my project wouldn't need to handle hundreds of events per second, so you've answered my question. I guess I simply wanted to understand if there was a more efficient way to go about it than saving each event to the DB if it was on a larger scale